# How to create an Array of actions and implement them in my Angular component?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, action

I have to modify the following code with an implementation of an Array of actions (bottom page).

I saw lots of websites by I wasn't able to find something than can be used for my code.

I will have to change my html , my tableService, my component.ts and oviously my actionConfiguration.

At the moment this is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of columns" (click)="sortTable(col)">{{col}}</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 5,
                                               currentPage: page,
                                               totalItems: users.length } ; let i = index">
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns">{{user[col]}}</td>
      <td>
        <button [ngClass]="getClassCondition(act)" *ngFor="let act of actions" (click)="actionFunc(act,i)">{{act}}</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div>
  <pagination-controls (pageChange)="page = $event"></pagination-controls>
</div>
```

This is my component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-table',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-table.component.css']
})

export class DynamicTableComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  users = [];
  @Input()
  columns: string[];
  @Input()
  actions: string[];


  @Input()
  class;

  direction = false;
  page: any;

  constructor() {
  }

  sortTable(param) {
    /*done*/
  }

  actionFunc(i, index) {
    if (i === 'deleteUser') {
      if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?') === true) {
        this.users.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
    if (i === 'editUser') {
      /*...*/
    }
  }

  getClassCondition(act) {
    return act === 'deleteUser'  ? this.class = 'btn btn-danger' : 'btn btn-primary' ;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

This is my tableService.ts

```
import { USERS } from './mock-data';

@Injectable()
export class TableService {

  constructor() { }

  static getUsers(): Observable<any[]> {
    return Observable.of(USERS).delay(100);
  }

  static getColumns(): string[] {
    return ['id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'age'];
  }

  static getActions(): string[] {
    return ['deleteUser', 'editUser'];
  }

}
```

Here's the new Task, I have to create an Array of Actions so I will be able to use it in different components but I have no idea how to do it.
I have to start from something like this, it's just an example (not complete because I don't know what to insert exactly):

actionConfig.ts

```
export const ACTIONS = [
  {
    label: 'Remove',
    actionType: 'deleteUser',
  },
  {
    label: 'Edit',
    actionType: 'editUser',
  },
];
```

Comment: did you have a look at [typescript enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)? Edit: you can have complex structures in them like in your `actionConfig.ts` file - but the data type would have to be `any`

Comment: Yes but as I'm new in angular I don't know how to apply it in my code... can you edit my code please?

Comment: hey, sorry for the late reply. I'll add a stackblitz in some time for you to refer - unless you have figured it out already.

Comment: Not yet, tell me what you know ;) thanks

Answer (score 0):

A sample of `Enum` and a table to show data on iterating on them:
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wyss75)

You also might want to read [typescript-enums-explained](https://medium.com/@katbusch/typescript-enums-explained-e5f9a101afc9)

Basically, the TypeScript enums are compiled to something as shown below for reverse lookup. Thats why I have added the `foreach` loop in constructor and created another list.

```
export enum Fruits {
    APPLE = 'Apple',
    MANGO = 'Mango',
    BANANA = 'Banana',
}
```

is compiled to

```
var Fruit;
(function (Fruit) {
    Fruit[Fruit["APPLE"] = 'Apple'] = "APPLE";
    Fruit[Fruit["MANGO"] = 'Mango'] = "MANGO";
    Fruit[Fruit["BANANA"] = 'Banana'] = "BANANA";
})(Fruit || (Fruit = {}));
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

HTML

```
<button [ngClass]="getClassCondition(act.actionType)" *ngFor="let act of actions"
              (click)="actionFunc(act, user)">{{act.label}}</button>
```

COMPONENTS.TS

```
actionFunc(action, element: any) {
    if (action.actionType === 'DELETE') {
      if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?') === true) {
        /*...*/
      }
    }
    if (action.actionType === 'GO_TO') {
     /*...*/
    }
  }
```

actionsConfig.ts

```
export const ACTIONS = [
  {
    label: 'Delete',
    actionType: 'DELETE',
    deleteApi: 'api/USERS'
  },
  {
    label: 'Edit',
    actionType: 'GO_TO',
    getUrl: row => '/detail/' + row.id,
  },
];
```